# How to roast mixed vegetables together?

Tags: vegetables, soup

For a soup, I want to roast carrots, potatoes, tomatoes, peas, onions etc., so what would be the procedure?

- If I put them together in a vessel and close the lid off, they'll get
  watery.
- If I put them together in a open vessel, they'll take hours to get
  roasted.

How do YOU roast vegetables for a mixed vegetable soup?

Is it preferable to roast on a flat pan or in a vessel with walls?

N.B.: I have the gas stove only.

Answer (score 1):

I try to cut them into pieces which take about the same amount of time to cook. Usually I'll do the carrots, potatoes, onions (and parsnips and sweet potato) together in one pot (45 minutes to an hour at 350); I've never roasted peas or tomatoes, but I would definitely do them separately, or add them nearer the end (say 25 minutes for the tomatoes, with the lid on, and 10-15 for the peas, but try experimenting).

Comment: I was talking of roasting on Gas, BTW.

Comment: have edited the question